# Handling error 500 by Interceptor in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, exception, interceptor

I have created my Interceptor class and have overridden only the afterCompletion method. 
When ever the system throws an error ( 500, 404 ), the system breaks and does not reach afterCompletion method of my interceptor. Is there any way so that the  request can reach the afterCompletion method with the exception occured.

Interceptor class

```
public class ClassName extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    if (ex != null) {
        //do somthing here
    }
}
```

}

interceptor declaration

```
   <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="x.y.z.ClassName" />
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Can anyone guide me one this.

Comment: The after completion method should always been called ... provided spring found a controller. If you call a non processed URL, the interceptor will never be called.

Comment: yeah spring found a controller and there i am causing a null pointer exception. From there it shows me 500 error page (due to NPE) and the control does not go to interceptor class.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot reproduce. I wrote a controller containing `throws new NullPointerException();`, and interceptor containing `logger.info("AfterCompletion", ex)` in the `afterCompletion` method and ... I can see the message in the logs along with the Exception !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using SWF + MVC and realized different ways of registering interceptors ,

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="DataCollectorFlowRegistry" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works for me.